# sudo apt-get update leads to crash of terminal application

Tags: apt, updates, sudo

I try to run `sudo apt-get update` and the terminal freezes and a message pops up: `Ubuntu experienced an internal error`...
I am trying to work with OpenFOAM and all the times is asking me to update things and when I try it, it gets stuck. 

 Ubuntu version is 12.04.

Comment: Please post your /etc/apt/sources.list file maybe it will give any clue.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. I am trying to do this but now it tells me Permission denied...

Comment: Did you tried to access it as root???

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I am sorry, I am very new to Linux. How do I access as a root? Right now I am accessing as the username I have by default in my laptop...

Comment: type the command in the terminal sudo su then type vim /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: alright! I have the list. I used this:  gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list I am trying to paste it but it tells me it's too long...

Comment: ok. Have you tried to use apt-get update as root user?

Comment: Try this maybe it will help open **terminal** :

    sudo apt-get install -f 

then 

    sudo apt-get update

Comment: wow! Thank you! at least now I get back my initial problem!! :) Now it tells me again:                                          E: Type ‘kill’ is not known on line 61 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.                                                             I had this problem before and I commented the line kill

Comment: thank you very much Tarun! If I type sudo apt-get install -f it tells me again You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems... when I run it, it tells me the same thing: type 'kill' is not known...

Comment: If I comment again the line 61 E: Type ‘kill’ is not known on line 61 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list  then when I run the sudo apt-get update, the terminal doesn't do anything....

Comment: I think the problem is in the sources.list file then. As you have commented the 'kill'. Try to use a frsh copy of sources.list and then type apt-get update as root user. You can find sources.list files contents on askubuntu.

Comment: Thanks again. I am now back to square one.... I try to update and I get 4 Warnings like this:W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/www.openfoam.org_download_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
... then if I run apt-get update...again! Also now if I try to see the /etc/apt/sources.list it opens an empty file... sorry for all this trouble! I'm very confused! any additional help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Make a back up copy of your sources.list:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list{,.backup}
```

Now remove the original and update:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list && sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I've tried this and it tells me there is no such list...grrrr!! Sorry if it's me causing all this problems due to my ignorance.....

Comment: After many attempts I found out that I managed to disable the universe repository and that was what didn't let me update properly openFOAM. Everything solved now and I am happy I didn't have to go for the solution DELETE EVERYTHING AND INSTALL AGAIN UBUNTU ... many thanks for all the support! I hope I can start helping as well some time soon!! :)

Comment: @Xulia : Glad to hear that :)